# Changed background color based on td number using ID

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble changing a background color of a table cell based on its value. I have made it work using the

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(td);
```

But I would like to make it check the number with an ID tag. The reason is because I will have multiple rows where the variable range of good and bad (green or red) will be different.

My javascript looks like:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("cho");
for (var i=0, m=elems.length; i<m; i++) {
if (elems[i].innerHTML>7)
  { elems[i].style.background="#ef0401";}
if (elems[i].innerHTML<=7)
  { elems[i].style.background="#4CB900";}
}
```

I tried looking this up, do I have to replace innerHTML with children?

Here is the HTML

```
<table class="medical">
  <tr>
    <td class="type-txt bg-left"><span class="type-name">Total Cholesterol</span><span class="sm-font">A Type of Fat</span></td>
    <td class="bg-right" id="cho">80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="type-txt bg-left"><span class="type-name">LDL</span><span class="sm-font">"Bad" Cholesterol</span></td>
    <td class="bg-right" id="ldl">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[A link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzm3tuhm/16/)

Comment: `var elems = document.getElementById("cho");` <-- um get**Element**ById returns *ONE* element. Not sure how you loop through one element.

Comment: you should only have one element with a specific id. `getElementById` will return a single element, not an array like `getElementsByTagName` does - will you have multiple `cho`-type cells on your page?

Comment: Are you know that the `id` property for a html element should be unique?

Comment: I was only planning on using the id for that cell only. cho = Cholesterol, I would use an id ldl - LDL (which would use a different equation for Green or Red background color. So >7 & <=7 would work for cho, a id ldl would need an equation >10 & <+10 to change the colors.

Comment: if you want to use id for one cell then go for elems.style.background="#ef0401"; since document.getElementById() only supports one name at a time and only returns a single node not an array of nodes

Comment: if you have multiple cells with same id (which is not recommended) and want to iterate then use jQuery framework. In this case, replacing document.getElementById("cho"); with $("#cho") will work.

Comment: I am only using the id for one cell only. "cho" would only be used once on this page. Different equations will use different id tags. That was my plan anyways.

Comment: If you are planning it to use only once then this will work.     var elems = document.getElementById("cho");
if (elems.innerHTML>7)
  { elems.style.background="#ef0401";}
if (elems.innerHTML<=7)
  { elems.style.background="#4CB900";}